# Repeating value columns and creating single value rows

Tags: sas

[image]

[image]

I need to get st8a to have one single value for each subgroup and for that single value to have it's own row just below "All Nangiobotide" in the treatment column for each subgrp. Anyone got any ideas on the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: In the data set or report? If you're using to populate a report, via PROC REPORT could you use it as a GROUP column which would achieve that functionality without affecting your raw source data? Otherwise you can use FIRST/LAST processing to identify the records and set them to missing. Please show what you've tried in that regards and we can help you.

Comment: @REEZA It is in the dataset but wouldn't first/Last processing just create a blank except for the the first or last observation you selected in the st8a column. It wouldn't be transformed into it's own row based on subgrp?. Its a footnote that I need to validate fro a production side table  so it needs to be on its own row

Comment: You can set flags. Show an example of what you have and what you want, and preferably not as images. To mock up an example I'd have to type out your data from the pictures and then solve it.